# Unable to recovery old btc address

Tags: bitcoind, btce

Yesterday someone transfer by accident some btc to my old address not used since 6 months. I knew i deleted all this, but last spent hour I was able to find my walltet. So I installed bitcoin core, few months before it looked different but ok, and replaced my walltet.dat , then when I launch it, it says : scanning, and then it starts but there is no any receiving address, can I somehow restore it ?

Comment: With what did you replace your wallet.dat? If there is no private key or wallet left, it is gone. Don't you have a copy on a USB drive and forgot about it?

Comment: Go to the debug console in Bitcoin Core, and type 'validateaddress [address]'. If it says 'ismine : true', the wallet considers that address its own (which may be the case even without it being listed as a receive address).

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have your private key, you will not be able to access that address.